# Shopping cart remove React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to remove an item. I send the item information but when I receive it in the reducer I do not know how to do it so that I delete it from the array.
I also tried indexOf but I do not know how to return it.

I am learning React and Redux, sorry for the inconvenience.

I can not think of how I can proceed.

```js
shopActions.js

import actionTypes from '../constants/actionTypes';

const addProduct = (name, description, price) => ({
 type: actionTypes.SHOP_ADD_PRODUCT,
 payload: {
  name,
  description,
  price
 }
});

const removeProduct = (item) => ({
 type: actionTypes.SHOP_REMOVE_PRODUCT,
 payload: item
});

export default { addProduct, removeProduct };
```

```css
Shop.js

import actionTypes from '../constants/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    orders: []
};



const shopReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.SHOP_ADD_PRODUCT: {
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                orders: [...state.orders, action.payload]
            });
        }
        case actionTypes.SHOP_REMOVE_PRODUCT: {
            console.log(action.payload)           
            return ;
        }

        default:
            return state;
    }

};



export default shopReducer;
```

```html
Products.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ProductItem from '../../components/ProductItem';
import CartItem from '../../components/CartItem';
import './Products.css';

// @Actions
import productsActions from '../../actions/productsActions';
import shopActions from '../../actions/shopActions';

class Products extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
  // Este getProducts debería conectarse a un servicio y traer de ahi los productos
  // Para nuestro jemeplo, los productos están hardcodeados (puestos a mano) en el reducer
  // Si quieren agregar o modificar productos, lo hacen directamente desde el reducer
  this.props.getProducts();
  // Dejo este getProducts aquí como ejemplo de donde debería llamarse para traer la información desde un servicio
 }

 addProduct(name, description, price) {
  this.props.addProduct(name, description, price);
 }

 removeProduct(item){
  this.props.removeProduct(item);
 }

    render() {
     const { products, shop } = this.props;

     const renderProducts = products.list ? products.list.map((products, index) => {
      return (
   
    <ProductItem 
     index={index} 
     product={products} 
     button={<button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={() => {this.addProduct(products.name, products.description, products.price);}}>
     Agregar al carrito</button>}/>
      );
     }) : null;

     // Lo siguiente son los productos agregados al carrito. Lo mismo que el caso anterior,
     // Mover todo a componentes, identificar y crearlos
     // Por ejemplo un componente llamado <Orders> que reciba por props los productos
     // Podrían crear una acción para quitar el producto del carrito
     const orders = shop.orders.length ? shop.orders.map((products, index) => {
      return (
       <CartItem product={products} button={<button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={() => {this.removeProduct(products);}}>
    BORRAR</button>} />    
      );
     }) : <p>No hay productos en el carrito</p>;
        return (
         <div>
             <h1>Productos</h1>
    <div className='groupOfCards'>
     {renderProducts}
    </div>             
             <h1>Carrito</h1>
    <table class="table productTable">
     <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item</th>
      <th scope="col">Cantidad</th>
      <th scope="col">Precio</th>
      <th scope="col">Borrar</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     {orders}
     </tbody>
    </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

/*
connect conecta la aplicación al store. Permite agregar datos y funciones a 
las props.
*/

export default connect(
    state => {
        return {
            products: state.productsReducer, // Saco los productos del reducer
            shop: state.shopReducer
        }
    },{
  addProduct: shopActions.addProduct,
  removeProduct: shopActions.removeProduct, // Uso una acción para agregar al carrito
        getProducts: productsActions.getProducts
    }
)(Products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to render the UI when you add or remove any element in your card the adding and deletion of an item should happen in an immutable way, I can see for adding you are using Object.assign which is fine in the same way when removing you need to use the [es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) filter on the existing array and set the state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `item.name` is a unique identifier(which it shouldn't be. you must use a 
save a unique id with it too) you can filter out the product from array and return it like

```
   case actionTypes.SHOP_REMOVE_PRODUCT: {
        const newOrders = state.orders.filter((item) => item.name !== action.payload.name);          
        return {...state, orders: newOrders }
    }
```

Comment: I had a same issue and this worked for me. thanks a lot @shubham Khatri

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is some unique key `id` exists in the product records.

```
case actionTypes.SHOP_REMOVE_PRODUCT: {

      let filteredOrder = state.orders.filter((product)=>product.id!=action.payload.id);
//filteredOrder  will hold record not having action.payload

      return
        Object.assign({}, state, {
        orders: [...filteredOrder]
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like how you added item to cart using Object.assign, to remove the item from the cart, first remove the item from the orders array using any of the array methods (like splice, filter) that seem fit and then use Object.assign to change the orders in the state object.

```
case actionTypes.SHOP_REMOVE_PRODUCT: { 
    let orders = state.orders.filter((item) => item !== action.payload);         
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
        orders: orders
    });
}
```